# what is this insect? just curious

Tags: species-identification

Thank you for replying my question..and sorry for my broken english (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GXs5.jpg)

Comment: @PriyanshuDas Answers should be posted as answers, not comments. Additionally, from [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* - we should encourage questions to be improved rather than answering ones that do not fit the guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. See this page: https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info for information on what we expect for species ID questions. Also please embed your image in your question rather than posting it as a link.